# Will Child workflow continue to run after parent is finished? (ChildPolicy.ABANDON)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, workflow, amazon-swf

I want to trigger child workflows from one workflow(parent). Basically this would happen in a loop in the decider

```
@Workflow
@WorkflowRegistrationOptions(defaultExecutionStartToCloseTimeoutSeconds = 240,
              defaultTaskStartToCloseTimeoutSeconds = 60)
public interface W1{
    @Execute(version = "1.0")
    void fn();
}

public class W1Impl implements W1{
    ChildClientFactory factory = new ChildClientFactoryImpl();

    @Override
    public void fn() {
       int i;
      /*
          I'll call activity1 that returns me a list(size = n)
          I trigger n child worflows(Each takes the content in the list and operates)
      */
       for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
          ChildClient childWorkflowClient = factory.getClient();
          childWorkflowClient.someMethod(params);//TRIGGERING CHILD WORKFLOW
      }
    }
}
```

The parent workflow need not wait for the child workflows to finish. i.e) the child workflows will do some processing based on the input to them and will put the result in a persistance store. 
So I'm not returning a `promise` from the child workflows.

**Note:** Child workflow's decider return type is `void`.

The `ChildPolicy` option on `WorkflowRegistrationOptions` has the option `ABANDON`

From the docs:

> ABANDON: Amazon SWF will take no action; the child executions will continue to run.

**Questions:**

1. When I don't return any Promise from the child workflow, will the parent workflow finish after triggering all child workflows?

i.e) after triggering `n` child workflows the parent must finish execution. The child will continue to run. (since i've specified `ChildPolicy.ABANDON`). Is this correct?

2. The `defaultExecutionStartToClosetimeoutSeconds` of parent need not consider(include) the timeout of the child workflows , right?

3.Are there any constraints on the rate at which child workflows are triggered? (Since I trigger workflows from a loop)

And is there anything that I need to take care of?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is going to complete. The parent workflow exits when all tasks including activities and child workflows are completed or failed. Internally workflow is invoked inside a [TryCatchFinally](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/04ea743936d1fd1a4e0555295418b3148c834a74/aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/core/TryCatchFinally.java) and completes only when *doFinally* is executed. It doesn't depend on child workflow returning any result as well as its child policy. Even if it returns void the generated workflow client still returns *Promise<Void>* and ignoring this promise is not going to change the behavior. It should be pretty straightforward to add *workflowClient.detach* method to disconnect parent from the child. It would complete [ExternalTask that controls the child workflow completion](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/6f22effec4337edab75fdbe5cde0ed81d2e6d5fd/aws-java-sdk-swf-libraries/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/worker/GenericWorkflowClientImpl.java#L214).

IMHO I wouldn't bother with detaching the clients as in this case any errors from them would be ignored. Keeping them attached ensures that parent gets exception if child fails for any reason.

As far as starting rate I wouldn't be very concerned. The more important limitation is the number of children that a single parent can have. Due to need to return the whole workflow history on every decision having too many children is not a good idea. I wouldn't recommend more than 100. If you need more, create a tree of workflows. Parent with 100 children each of them creating their own 100 children gives 10k children.

Starting an independent workflow from an activity using generated *external client* is a possible workaround. Just make sure that possible failure conditions like workflow starting and then activity failing due to communication error are handled correctly. Use [ActivityExecutionContext](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/ActivityExecutionContext.html) to access reference to the SWF endpoint and other related information.

Comment: I'm now thinking to start the child workflows from an activity in parent.. Is it possible? And I'm going to make all child workflows run parallely. (i.e _I'm not going to pass Promise<Void> as a parameter which would make them sequential_). In this case if the timeout of parent is slightly greater than timeout of  **one child workflow** is it enough?

Comment: Updated comment with "start from activity" answer

Comment: If I start a child workflow from one of the activities, then the activity won't wait for the child workflow to finish?

Comment: Starting workflow using external client (which should be used from an activity) is synchronous operation which returns as soon as workflow execution is started. So activity doesn't wait for workflow to finish. It also doesn't get any feedback about workflow execution.

Comment: You mean **asynchronous**?

Comment: Also, why do you say starting workflow using external client should be done only from activity? we can also do it from the decider as my post says

Comment: Synchronous in the sense that it blocks until workflow is started. There are two types of clients normal and external. Your post uses the normal one which should be used from withing a workflow code. The external is named ChildClientFactoryExternal and ChildClientFactoryExternalImpl

Comment: If I use the normal client in activity will the behaviour be the same? i.e activity won't wait for the workflow to finish?

Answer (score 1):

1) nope (updated). see Maxim's answer below
2) if you are abandoning them, the timeouts on the child workflows matter. Only thing you should worry about (as far as timeouts go) is that the parent workflow will timeout before getting a chance to launch all child workflows.
3) SWF may throttle you if you make a large amount of calls in a short period of time (and I've seen it happen), but the doc is not clear on what large means and what the period of time is. See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/developerguide/swf-dg-limits.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the doc I cannot find about the `rate` at which child workflows can be triggered? It only says `applications may be throttled if they make a large number of API calls in a very short period of time.`

Comment: what I was saying above is that it's not documented.

Comment: So how can I make sure that it doesn't throttle and runs properly?

Comment: one approach is to catch the throttle exception. another approach (what I would do) is to actually wrap launching the children workflows in an activity and configure retries on those activities so that you are sure they went through. SWF will do the retrying for you (also make sure to wait for all activities to complete before closing the parent workflow)

Comment: So is it possible to trigger workflows from an activity? I thought I can do it from the decider only

Comment: It is possible using external client the same way it is done from any other external process

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are interested in starting external workflows and not child workflows. Best practice would be to start the workflows from an activity in the parent workflow. That way there is no hierarchy created. 
Also when starting the workflows and activities from decision worker the rate is controlled ( from what I remember it is 10 activites and 4 child workflows per second, it can be increased by talking to swf team). Some spikes are allowed but if the rate does not go down then you would start getting rateexceededexception ( not throughput or throttle). 
However no such issue if you start it from an activity which then is equivalent to just starting new workflows.

Comment: It is a child workflow. From the docs, `When a workflow execution is started from the context of another workflow execution, it is called a child workflow execution`

Comment: But if you want to start a new workflow and don't want any relationship created between existing and new workflow execution then you need to start an external workflow. And that needs to be done not from a decision worker but an activity worker.

Comment: So will the current workflow exist till all triggered workflows gets finished?

Comment: No. Current workflow will not wait for any other workflows to finish. It will simply start them and and end. All new external workflows started will run and end at a later time.